# Appending new columns to table based on matching to second table

Tags: r, match

I have two tables selectVDem and DT.

DT has columns marking out country, month-year and year

```
       Country MonthofDate Size Year
   1:    Benin  1997-01-01   18 1997
   2:    Benin  1997-02-01   18 1997
   3:    Benin  1997-03-01   18 1997
   4:    Benin  1997-04-01   18 1997
   5:    Benin  1997-05-01   18 1997
  ---                               
3506: Zimbabwe  2015-07-01   38 2015
3507: Zimbabwe  2015-08-01   38 2015
3508: Zimbabwe  2015-09-01   42 2015
3509: Zimbabwe  2015-10-01   42 2015
3510: Zimbabwe  2015-11-01   42 2015
```

whereas selectVDem has the following headings

```
Year Country EqualityResources EqualityProtec PercentSufferage   LocalGov  RegionGov ExecCorrupt PolCorrupt
```

I want to append the EqualityResources EqualityProtec PercentSufferage   LocalGov  RegionGov ExecCorrupt PolCorrupt values to the end of the DT table as new columns based where the year and country values match. Is there any way I can do this without using a for loop? I have tried two ways already.

```
DT$EqualityResources <- subset(DT$Country == selectVDem$Country & DT$Year == `selectVDem$Year, select =  EqualityResources)`
```

this causes the error

```
Error in subset.default(DT$Country == selectVDem$Country & DT$Year ==  : 
  argument "subset" is missing, with no default
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In `==.default`(DT$Country, selectVDem$Country) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In DT$Year == selectVDem$Year :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I have also tried writing a function and using the apply function

```
getVDem <- function(vDemVal, country, year, vDem){
  result <- vDem[vDem$Country == country & vDem$Year == year,]
  finalResult <- vDem$vDemVal
  return(finalResult)
}

DT$EqualityResources <- apply(DT, 1, getVDem(selectVDem, DT$Country, `DT$Year,'EqualityResources'))#subset(selectVDem,DT$Country == Country & DT$Year == Year, select = EqualityResources)`
```

which gives me the error

> Error in vDem$Country : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

What should I do?

Comment: Is it like a merge? you are trying to merge the columns from selectVDem to DT based on country and year - correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Kind of, it can't be a merge because DT has many more rows than selectVDem as DT has a row for each month-year while selectVDem has only rows for year. However, I am wondering whether it would be possible to take the info from selectVDem for Benin 1997 and add it to all 12 rows in 1997 in DT.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do it by columns is likely to create a mess. You can use dplyr's join group of functions, most likely left_join. Having matching column names can make the joins automatically determine the "by" arguments, *BUT be careful if you have matching column names and different column contents!* :

```
library(dplyr)
newDT <- left_join(DT, selectVDem)
```

The advantage of left_join to merge is that you do not include any categories (in your case Years or Countries), that do not exist in the left object. Automating the by argument can also be an advantage.